# jQuery animation not working at all

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function(){
    $(".title").animate({left:"170px"},250);
    console.log("this is working");
})
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="portfolioimages">
        <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
        <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
        <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
    </div>
```

I want to slide the "TITLE" text to the right, but for some reason it's not working. I put the console.log line there to test if the mouseover event is working, but it's not even being called. I have other functions in the same js file and those work fine, they're both under the same document ready function too. I can't figure out why it isn't working. Thanks

.title is positioned absolutely while .porfolioimages is positioned relatively

Comment: You don't see the error in the console about the invalid syntax?

Comment: `.animate({left:"170px"},250);` instead of `.animate({left:"170px",250});`

Comment: It works fine if you include jQuery @JJJ

Comment: He doesn't use `animate`, he uses `css`. See my answer.

Comment: @StuntHacks jQuery makes `{left:"170px",250}` valid syntax?

Comment: This is an obvious syntax error. It works when fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/von75gh3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple syntax error, an object cannot have a non-labeled entry, although a multidimensional array can, but that's beside the point, `.animate()` [requires an object](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) here with the `250` passed as a plain argument for duration.

Assuming `position: relative`:

```js
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function() {
    $(".title").animate({
        left: "170px",
    }, 250);
    console.log("this is working");
});
```

```css
.title {
    position: absolute;
}
.portfolioimages {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't realize the closed bracket was in the wrong place. However, I fixed it, but it still did not work. I forgot to mention that .title has the property position:absolute while .portfolioimages has the property position:relative

Comment: You have to explain "it still did not work". When I edit that in, I get the paragraph text over the `title` text, but nothing you've specified says anything about how you're handling anything else. What is the problem?

Comment: So, as I mentioned in the question, I want to get the title to slide over. I ran your code snippet and it worked there, however, I copied over your jQuery code and tested that out in my js file, however, the nothing changed, the file remained as it was when I loaded the page. "title" slides over when I take it out of the event, but not when it is inside the event, so it seems as though there is an issue calling the mouseover or mouseenter event

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: I have not uploaded the website to a domain, I can edit my question to include more of my code, but anything specific you think you'd need to determine the issue?

Comment: Unless you can produce a working example demonstrating the problem, I'm going to delete this answer. Check the console, make sure you've hard-reloaded the script and that it's running AFTER the element is in the DOM.

Comment: If you don't know how to debug javascript in the browser, see [MDN's guide here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript).

Comment: Here is a link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yagdg6w/     I have removed the image because the jQuery command is supposed to run when it enters the div, so the image should have no effect on it.

Comment: It's the negative `z-index`, it's buried and is not triggering the `mouseover`. https://jsfiddle.net/0yagdg6w/1/

Comment: Of course it is. Thank you so much, I'm surprised I couldn't figure out such a small issue. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2):

**1st-** If as you said *I have other functions in the same js file and those work fine,* so this mean you include jquery

**2nd-** you have a `Unexpected token ,` error with your code

**3rd-** as I pointed on comment

> use `.animate({left:"170px"},250);` instead of
>   `.animate({left:"170px",250});`

**4th-** I think no need to use `mouseover` use `mouseenter` instead .. and use `mouseleave` to return back to the default position

**The next demo will also help if you have more of `portfolioimages` divs titles**

```js
$(".portfolioimages").on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(".title").not($(this).find(".title")).stop().animate({left:"0px"} ,250 );
    $(this).find(".title").stop().animate({left:"170px"} ,250 );                                                    //-^-not-^-
    console.log("this is working");
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(".title").stop().animate({left:"0px"} ,250 );  
})
```

```css
body *{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}
.portfolioimages{
  position: relative;
}
.title{
  position : absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
  background : red;
  color: #fff;
  padding : 5px;
  text-align : center;
  width : 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
    <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `mouseenter` is a good recommendation, since it will cut down on the number of times the handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `left`-attribute only works for elements with `position:absolute;`. You can either use `margin-left` or `padding-left` for this (both may look the same but actually have a different effect: `margin` moves the entire element, `padding` moves the content inside the element):

```js
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function() {
  $(".title").css("margin-left", "170px");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolioimages">
  <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
  <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
  <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
```

And if you use the `animate`-function:

```js
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function() {
  $(".title").animate({marginLeft: "170px"}, 250);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolioimages">
  <p class="slidetext title">TITLE</p>
  <p class="slidetext description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in convallis dolor. Ut ut eros justo. Nulla sem metus, bibendum et ultricies eget, vulputate tempor libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et</p>
  <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer to use the .animate event. Also, .title is positioned absolutely, not relatively.

Comment: @Sal Yes, I prefer the `.animate`-function as well. However, my answer was made for an earlier version of the question which used the `.css`-function. I didn't realize at the time that the question was edited. That's why I added the second part.